# Assign button value within a loop - Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

```
        @foreach($sections as $section)
            <div class="main_content_body">
                <div class="main_content_bodyhead">
                    <h4>{{ $section->section_name }}</h4>
                    {{ $section->id }}
                    <button id="Knowthesection" value="{{ $section->id }}" type="button" class="button1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updatesectionmodal" onclick=getsectionid()>
                        Update section name
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="main_content_bodycontent">
                    <td>content 1</td><br><br>
                    <td>content 2</td>
                </div>
            </div>
        @endforeach

<script>
    function getsectionid(){
        var sec_id = document.getElementById('Knowthesection').value;
        alert(sec_id);
    }
</script>
```

I try to assign the value for the button within a loop. But when I alert the value out. It always shows the first looping value. The section->id above the button is display perfectly, but the section->id within the button is not. Do anyone know the reason? How can i solve it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you cannot use same ids for mutliple elements . **Quick fix** : you can pass `this` inside your function here `onclick=getsectionid(this)` then in your function use `function getsectionid(el) {var sec_id = el.value;alert(sec_id);}`

Comment: It works!! I didn't notice the id will be repeated in a looping. Thank you so much. I learn a lot.